# xtext: how to use grammar besides Eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I am trying to use the example org.eclipse.xtext.example.arithmetics.Arithmetics with xtext. I can run the Eclipse Application as described in the [5-minute tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/010-xtext-in-5-minutes.php) and [15-minute tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/020-domainmodel-step-by-step.php), so the editor will do syntax checking.

But how do I actually use the model in a Java app? (I'm not talking about code generation)

I found this [FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/FAQ#How_do_I_load_my_model_in_a_standalone_Java_application.C2.A0.3F). But which .jar files do I need to include in my build path? There are a lot of unresolved classes here.

```
new org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup().setPlatformUri("../");
Injector injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);
resourceSet.addLoadOption(XtextResource.OPTION_RESOLVE_ALL, Boolean.TRUE);
Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(
    URI.createURI("platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/example.mydsl"), true);
Model model = (Model) resource.getContents().get(0);
```

Comment: (And I don't mean MyDslStandaloneSetup, I've changed that to my own class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Xtext without eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840685/is-it-possible-to-use-xtext-without-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to find all dependency jars yourself you can use Rightclick on Project -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar file as a help to collect all dependency jars

Answer (score 0):

These are the dependencies I found:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/gabor/eclipse2/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils_1.2.1.v201112070431.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib"  path="D:/gabor/eclipse2/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/gabor/eclipse2/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/gabor/eclipse2/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar"/>
```

And the dsl project with the generated sources of course.
Not a nice solution, I pressed ctrl-shift-t, searched for the missing classes, and the list showed in which jars does eclipse find that class, and then I added that jar as External Jar to my classpath.